# Model binding via templates causes different names for html tages. How to refer these in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

Let's say I have a model class,

```
public class NameModel
{
    public string Title     { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName  { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Titles 
    {
        get
        {
            var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Mr.", Value = "Mr." });
            list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Mrs.", Value = "Mrs." });
            list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Ms.", Value = "Ms." });

            return list;
        }
    }

    public NameModel()
    {

    }

    public NameModel(string first, string last) 
    {
        this.FirstName = first;
        this.LastName = last;
    }
}
```

This class is used in view named ShowName.cshtml as follows

```
@model MyTestApp.Models.NameModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, Model.Titles, Model.Titles)
<br />
@Html.LabelFor( m => m.LastName) 
@Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.LastName)       
<br />
@Html.LabelFor( m => m.FirstName) 
@Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.FirstName)
```

I am using this class as a template ( meaning referred via EditFor ), So in one case when this class is used for Employee, in HTML the text box for LastName will have an id of Employee_LastName whereas if i used it for Manager, HTML id for this text box will be Manager_LastName. Problem is that if I have certain java-script/JQuery that uses these identifier, how can I refer to these text boxes because their Ids changed based upon where they are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating your textbox as below

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName,new {id="LastName"})
```

Or you can add css class and refer your controls using the class selector

Answer (score 1):

Use class selectors instead of id selectors. So instead of:

```
$('#Manager_LastName')...
```

give the corresponding input a class and then:

```
$('.LastName')...
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try to get both:

$('#Manager_LastName, #Employee_LastName')...

or use the 'ends with' syntax:

$('[id$=_LastName]')...